# Conditional #include if sfunction block is present in model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm creating a Simulink (Embedded Coder) Target and some sfunction drivers for that target. In the main template file (TLC) I need to include some header file and call an initialization function if at least one driver block is present in the model.

For example, if my model uses the IO sfunction driver block, in `rpp_srmain.tlc` (the name of my template file) I need something like :

```
%<LibSetSourceFileSection(cFile, "Includes", tmpBuf)>
%openfile tmpBuf
%<IfBlockPresentInModel("gio")>
#include "gio.h"
%<EndIf>
%closefile tmpBuf
(...)
%<LibSetSourceFileSection(cFile, "Declarations", tmpBuf)>
%openfile tmpBuf
void main(void)
{
    %<IfBlockPresentInModel("gio")>
    gioInit();
    %<EndIf>
    (...)
}
```

Any help on how to accomplish this is very welcome.

Comment: What kind of S-Function is your "gio" IO driver block? 
Assuming it is an inlined S-Function, why aren't you including this #include and init function call in the block's TLC code instead of in the main TLC?

Comment: Because I didn't know what I was doing. So yes, that's basically the answer. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "gio" IO driver block is an [inlined S-Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/tlc/inlining-s-functions.html) (which is usually the case if you are using Simulink/Embedded Coder), you can include the block specific code in the block's TLC instead of the main TLC.

For example it could look something like this:

```
%implements "gio" "C"

%function BlockTypeSetup(block, system) Output

  %% include header files
  %openfile buffer
  #include "gio.h"
  %closefile buffer
  %<LibCacheIncludes(buffer)>

%endfunction


%function Start(block,system) Output
{
    gioInit();
}
%endfunction
```